# How should I respond when I lied about my education and the company finds out through background check?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, hiring-process, ethics, employer-relations

I lied about my education to my employer and background check revealed I did not graduate. How do I respond to my employer after they send me the following?

> In order for us to move forward and complete the background check investigation, we need to understand the reason for the discrepancy and know about your highest level of education completed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91412/discussion-on-question-by-isaac-wright-how-should-you-respond-if-you-lied-about).

Comment: Can you please clarify whether this is a job you already have, or a job that you are in the process of applying for?

Comment: Two questions: you say "your employer" but this is the sort of thing that happens *before* they employ you; can you clarify the scenario you're describing? What exactly are they "moving forward" on? Second, you say that you "lied about your education"; can you say a little bit about why you lied? A lie is a deliberate attempt to mislead; why did you make this attempt? That will help us advise you about good next steps.

Comment: @EricLippert That's usually true, but sometimes background checks may be conducted after someone is already employed. For example, I've known of cases with friends where they had background checks going on months after they started working at a job that required a security clearance, just due to the backlog of background checks that needed to be conducted. They just had to work on unclassified stuff until the security clearance was completed.

Comment: @Pharap It would be a much better question if it made the stage of employment clear (before starting, just started, worked there for 10 years).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's what I was going after with my line of questioning; (1) is this a matter between a current employer and an employee, or between a possible employer and a prospective employee? It might make a difference; for example, my legal insurance forbids me from using it to defend myself against my current employer.  And (2), was there intent to defraud?

Comment: (2) Intent to defraud is intention to deceive others, and to induce such other person, in reliance upon such deception, to assume, create, transfer, alter, or terminate a right, obligation, or power of a property. The prosecution would have to establish that the accused a. made the false statement b. intended it to assume, create, etc. I should think that provision of a resume accompanying an application for employment would provide (a) and (b).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will job offer be rescinded after education check due to unfinished degree?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/132161/will-job-offer-be-rescinded-after-education-check-due-to-unfinished-degree)

Comment: What was the nature of the "not graduating" part?  Was it that you earned the degree but some technicality showed up like failing to pay a campus housing bill?  Did the coursework but fell a few points short on a final exam or two?  Didn't finish the last year due to caring for your Downs Syndrome brother?  Took one semester and quit?  Bought the diploma from a similarly named sham school?

Answer (score 219):

**In some locations, it is a crime to provide certain types of false information to a potential employer. If this is the case where you are, or you are not sure, you should consider [Eric Lippert's Answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/132243/how-should-i-respond-when-i-lied-about-my-education-and-the-company-finds-out-th/132335#132335). Otherwise read on:**

Side note: they are very professional.

You should own up to the the lie, apologise, be honest about the reasons why you lied, indicate that you are committed to learning from the experience, ask for a second chance to prove your trustworthiness, and thank them for giving you an opportunity to explain yourself.

Then you should indicate what your actual highest level of education is, and **don't lie this time**.

Your chances are very slim. Hopefully you can rationalise why you were dishonest with them in a way that they are willing to accept. But I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Emphasis on the **don't lie this time**

Comment: Also, plus one on the side note. This is definitely a laudable attitude on the part of the employer.

Comment: I'm surprised they even bothered telling OP about it.  I would expect the employer would just drop the candidate and move on.

Comment: I had a coworker previously who was found out for lying about certifications. They owned up to it and got the job, turning out to be a good coworker. It does happen.

Comment: 2nd emphasis on **very slim**. People have made very successful careers, only to have it all taken away from them 20 years later due to being caught lying on their resume that they used to get their foot in the door. There's a politician or professor that comes to mind, but the name evades me.

Comment: It is conceivable that the university made an error and reported the status of some other student, so if one actually did graduate this is an opportunity to correct the university’s error. Not highly likely, but...

Comment: @Nelson They're informing them in case they made a mistake.  For example, the applicant could have graduated under one name, but now use another (marriage, legal name change, sex change, etc).  Or they could have contacted the wrong school (U of Chicago vs U of Illinois Chicago).

Comment: @JonCuster since the OP has indicated that he lied, I doubt it's an error on the university's part.

Comment: @FreeMan, true enough, but other folks seeking an answer (which really is the target of SE in general) might have gotten a similar message, yet have graduated.

Comment: This strikes me as extraordinarily bad advice. The OP may have committed a serious crime; confessing to it does not benefit them. The OP should probably stop talking to anyone and get a lawyer.

Comment: @EricLippert From what I've read, this seems unlikely unless he made a statement under oath that he had a degree that he didn't have. Although if it happens in Texas, Kentucky or New Jersey, he could indeed have a problem if they decide to prosecute.

Comment: @BobRodes: It is a class C felony in the state of Washington to lie about your education on a resume. Five years in jail, $10000 fine.  **The OP should contact a lawyer and stop taking advice from random strangers on the internet who say things like "from what I've read..."**.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for the information. I have added a warning to my post.

Comment: @EricLippert I did read several statements from attorneys that it prosecution in a situation like this was unlikely. For example, the Washington statute was created to go after "diploma mill" fraud. But as you say, that isn't any reason to risk getting in trouble with the law. So I take back my statement. He needs to check out his legal situation before he decides what to say to the employer.

Comment: Agree with Eric - admitting that they committed fraud will almost surely not give them the job. Worse, it could be used as incriminating evidence leading to a felony on their record, which would make finding jobs even more difficult possibly forever. There are no upsides, only downsides, to admitting committing fraud. Dead-cold silence, for instance, is a simple alternative that results in less downside risk. These are decisions for a lawyer to help with.

Answer (score 108):

> I lied about my education to my employer and background check revealed I did not graduate. How do I respond to my employer after they send me the following?

- The presupposition of the question is a bad supposition. **You do not respond.** You're in a hole of your own digging; stop digging.
- You stop soliciting legal advice from strangers on the internet and get it from a lawyer.
- Once you have a lawyer, ask them if you have committed fraud or any other crime, and how you should proceed so as to decrease your risk of being prosecuted if you have.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: I'm suggesting that the OP **get a lawyer and ask them what to do**.  They might have committed a crime; that's the high-order bit, not the job.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Fraud is a crime pretty much everywhere. Don't think of it as "lying on a resume". Think of it as an attempt to defraud a company, because that's what it is. Now, as for whether it is a "felony" or not varies by jurisdiction, but that's hardly relevant. Here, I'll edit the text to say "crime" instead, how's that?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: But to answer your specific question: in my home state of Washington, it is a class C felony to lie about your education on a job application. Five years in prison, $10000 fine.

Comment: The original poster should stop taking advice from people who are googling the law and *get a lawyer*.

Comment: I second the line of **do not respond**. Whether the situation is serious enough to get a lawyer, one would need to know more. Presumably the OP is in enough of a financial hole already.

Comment: You could add that if the OP is in the US (and possible other countries) on a working visa, they should not leave the country. Lying about education (or former jobs) on a job application can be a violation of the visa conditions that can result in a permanent ban an immigration officer may not show as much clemency as a court. +1 for having to get a lawyer right now.

Comment: The only legal advice you can ever trust from anyone other than a lawyer is "get a lawyer." This includes strangers, friends, family, the internet, the train, the cafe, work, and the lobby of a lawyer's office.

Comment: @EricLippert You may want to add that note about the Class C felony to the end of your answer, to help support the seriousness of the issue.  I mean, that specific law may not directly apply to the asker's case, as they may live elsewhere, but it lends credibility to the idea that there may be cause to shell out for a lawyer.

Comment: @EricLippert : And how often is it enforced? How high are the chances for the company actually suing the applicant, instead of just throwing the CV into the wastebin and maybe adding the name to a blacklist? I'm not trivializing the offense the OP committed, but is it really necessary to hire a lawyer for everything, even before receiving any lawsuit?

Comment: @Val: Those would be excellent questions **to ask a lawyer**, which is what the OP should be doing.

Comment: @Val: Some questions that can be answered without a lawyer are (1) is it a good idea to attempt to defraud a company that has lawyers? and (2) given that OP has attempted to defraud them, is it a good idea to confess that to them? and (3) when one has committed a crime, should one get legal advice from strangers on the internet who are not lawyers?

Comment: @EricLippert and in addition, if the advice of strangers on the internet gets you jail time and a massive fine, would they step up and help you out?

Answer (score 62):

I would say that you take it as a life lesson, and be more scrupulous about preserving your integrity in the future.  I would also say it's safe to assume that you've blown your chances of getting this job.

Honest people aren't people who are never dishonest, they are people who regret their moments of dishonesty, and are not dishonest in quite the same way again. By admitting that you haven't been entirely truthful, you've made a step in the direction of being an honest man, and a step away from the direction of being a dishonest one.

Now, you'll need to ask yourself why, and you probably ought to spend some time soul-searching before you try to explain it to the employer. (Things like being scared of not being able to find a job come to mind.) When you do attempt to explain yourself to the employer, you might start by saying that you recognize that you have blown your chances of getting hired, but that you wanted to speak on a personal level. Then pretty much bare your soul, in 100 words or fewer. (Not to try to get the job back, but to get it out of your system.) Then apologize and leave it at that. (You could thank them for the life lesson, too, if you can be sincere about it.)

(EDIT: Eric Lippert has pointed out that there are laws in some states that criminalize lying about your education on a resume. I would suggest that you get a lawyer's advice before telling the employer that you did this.)

Finally, you can be glad that you got caught now, instead of two or three years in. If you are an honest man, it would have eaten at you, and you would feel relieved when it finally came out in spite of the fallout. If you aren't an honest man, you'd probably find that you were unable to talk your way out of it, assuming you hadn't been fired already for some other lapse of integrity.

So, man up, face the consequences, forgive yourself (even if other people don't), do your best to put it right, and don't do it again.

Comment: If OP has blown the chances of getting the job, then what are the benefits of "baring their soul" versus just withdrawing the application?

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, firstly, we're just *assuming* he's blown his chances.  (I agree it's the most likely outcome, but there's a *tiny chance* this employer might defy the odds yet.)  Being honest keeps that door open, however slim the chances may be.  Walking away without explanation *definitely* closes it.  Also, depending on the industry OP is in, word might travel to other employers about this guy who lied on his resume.  Taking the time to explain himself (no matter the reasoning) can't possibly make him look *worse* than ghosting as soon as he gets caught in a lie.

Comment: "you've made a step in the direction of being an honest man, and a step away from the direction of being a dishonest one." I get what you mean here but I think it comes off as kind of judgmental of OP. There's an interpretation of this where you're calling them a dishonest man, which wouldn't be fun to read (despite the topic of their post)

Comment: @dataprincess the first two words of the question are "I lied". Dishonesty isn't an implication here, it's a fact to be dealt with.

Comment: @NateEldredge, The OP said, "I lied ... to my *employer*" and "How do I respond to my *employer* ..." I took this to mean the background check wasn't done before the OP joined the company.

Comment: @BobRodes Not sure what you are saying in the second paragraph, especially the first sentence "Honest people aren't people who are never dishonest...". What is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: @hobbs, I get that. There's a difference between talking about someone's dishonest act and calling them a dishonest man. That's all I mean to say.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's part of the process of owning it IMO. If you just walk away when you get found out, then you're not so motivated to be honest next time.

Comment: @dataprincess If you see it as judgmental to say that someone has been dishonest, then you are saying that dishonesty is "wrong." That in itself is a judgment. I'm not saying that someone should or shouldn't be honest or dishonest. That's not within my abilities to know. I'm just saying what I see. Dishonesty is saying that what isn't is. If you admit to having done that, then you now have made a step away from what isn't and towards what is. Maybe that's a better way of putting it?

Comment: @Confuzing I've never met anyone who was never dishonest, in particular with themselves. And that includes me. To me, an honest man or woman is one who does their best to find the things in themselves that they aren't being honest about, admit to them, and correct them. Not someone who is always honest. Anyone who thinks that he is always honest isn't being entirely honest with himself in my experience.

Comment: @BobRodes what I'm saying is judgmental is calling someone "a dishonest man." Saying they committed a dishonest act is different. It's not a huge deal but in conversations like these I find it helps to keep the focus on the action and less on the person. But your points are well taken.

Comment: @dataprincess I see your point as well. I'd say from the context, though, of taking steps towards one or the other, that I am actually speaking of the action of moving towards an archetype that never really exists in pure form, and away from another one. As for the idea of judgment, IMO all judgment is null and void, because, despite our perceptions to the contrary, we are incapable of either "good" or "bad" judgment. The one exception to that, the one judgment that we are able to make that is purely true, is that all people have absolute love for all of creation, including all other people.

Answer (score 20):

How close are you to graduating?

**If You're Not Close**

If you're not close, the other answers are spot on. Please read them and come clean.

**If You Are Close**

If you are close, contact your school. Find out everything you need to graduate. It may not just be credits, there are often money issues that can prevent you from showing as graduated, too. Get the full list.

Now, respond to your employer along the lines of "I contacted my school, and it turns out you're right, I'm not showing as graduated to them. I spoke with a counselor and received the full list of what I need to show as graduated, and will be remedying the situation as soon as possible. I hope that this will not impede my ability to work here, as I am very excited to be here, etc etc."

It shows you admit that there's a problem, and that you're taking the initiative to remedy the problem. If they keep you on (and yes, that's still very much a big if), make sure you do take those steps, though.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Agreed. This could be a solid tactic coupled with an honest response to the question of why the discrepancy exists. 'I'm sorry, this is why this happened, and this is what I am doing to remedy it."

Comment: As an anecdote: **This actually happened to me**. I completed all my credits, and intentionally skipped my graduation ceremony because I was going to grad school and didn't care. Turns out: I never submitted my request to graduate, and so when a company that had offered me a job conducted a background check, they found that even though I had said that I graduated, the school disagreed! I wrote them back to the effect of "Turns out you're right, I didn't graduate" and then immediately filed for it. Thankfully they were understanding (I really did have all the credits) and we went forward.

Comment: @Abigail I like those odds better than "yeah, I lied, you caught me."

Comment: @dlev I once was prevented from showing as graduated because I owed the school around $3,000 that loans didn't cover. Luckily, it didn't stop me from getting a job, and I eventually paid it off. Sometimes, somebody not graduating is over a really minor issue that shouldn't effect how employable they are.

Comment: @Abigail It may increase the chances of not being prosecuted for fraud.

Answer (score 9):

Be as honest as possible. If you were on track to graduate but fumbled at last minute that is understandable. But otherwise very hard to save this, if there was a less positive explanation.

Keep whatever you say simple and truthful.

Comment: Fumbling your course at the last minute may be understandable, but later pretending that you did not is not.

Comment: The overriding concern is going to be that you lied, not that you aren't fully qualified. Unless there's something about the wording of your resume that makes it ambiguous (and that's still not a good look) I don't think there's any comeback from this.

Answer (score 5):

I am tempted to claim this as a duplicate of ["How can I fix my relationship with my 7 month old cat after I've constantly abused her the past month?"](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/how-can-i-fix-my-relationship-with-my-7-month-old-cat-after-ive-constantly-abus).  While this may sound ludicrous, the problem is the same: you have broken a fundamental rule of social interaction for a relation that ultimately is dependent on mutual trust and trustworthiness.  This is a question of the "how can I resume using a bridge I have burnt?" kind.

This bit will determine the stance of management and HR towards you in future because it casts into doubt everything that needs to be trusted at face value in a robust relationship.

You probably should consider polishing your resume.  Or in this case, unpolishing it.  It is quite likely that you'll be better off moving elsewhere even in case that your current employer can be made to swallow that toad (likely at a price).

Comment: I'm not used to recommendations of making a resume look less polished.  But since the last resume was apparently over-polished, "unpolishing it" strangely sounds rather sensible.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to own up to not having a degree.  If you are close to having or it's a paperwork issue explain that.

Many companies do a minimal clearance when they hire and as the company takes on new clients or changes in insurance requirements, they will often do in depth background checks.

I worked for a company that did in-depth background checks every 5 years. The equivalent of an FBI Check. Be prepared that companies can retrieve information very cheaply on their employees and use it to their advantage.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused as to why there is a background check after you are employed rather than before. I'd also need to know how long you have been employed. That makes a big difference. Also, is this a highly skilled position? And does your intended degree really matter?

If the job is software engineering and your degree was art history, then having the degree is largely irrelevant, and you could come right out and say that. A sales job is another job where your choice of degree is often not meaningful. So, it's still a lie, but it's not a grievous one. You can probably talk your way out of it.

If the job is software engineering, then you are lucky, because that is a field where being self-taught is not usually a liability, and plenty of people never finished their degrees. Famously, Bill Gates and Mark Zuckerberg, and lots of others who are lesser known. But you need some credibility. You need some kind of proof that a degree would make no difference to your performance, and that's where it would be nice if you had already worked there a year or more. If this is the case, then you can probably talk your way out of it.

If this is a job that you just started, and you have established no credibility or meaningful performance, then I the only reasonable option is to fall on your sword and offer your resignation. It's not likely they will keep an unknown entity that has been caught in a lie. I wouldn't even try to explain the lie. Note, I didn't say quit. I said offer your resignation. They may accept it (the most likely scenario), but they may not. If they don't accept it immediately, it's because they like you for some reason and they will probably call you in to explain the lie. If you don't have a really, really good explanation, then don't waste their time.

Comment: One example could be for a government clearance. Most people aren't given a background check for that *before* they are hired. Another example is that many companies don't do an in-depth background check upon hiring but if something comes to light afterward they will initiate a more thorough check. You see this in the news at least once or twice a year where a high level person comes under scrutiny for some reason and it is discovered that they lied about their education or work history.

Comment: I once had a colleague who messed up a customer project very badly, in ways only someone lacking the basic knowledge his resume said he had could. Customer threatened to sue for misrepresenting the guy, my employer ordered a thorough background check of his resume and found the entire thing was a solid pack of lies (normally here your resume is taken on good faith, most often that's no problem). He got fired on the spot, and got some serious claims for damages against him.

Comment: I had an employer do a background check on me after I had worked there for a few years. They had simply increased the requirements for employment, so they could win more government contracts or something. They applied it to new hires first but eventually got around to checking pre-existing employees like myself.

Answer (score -16):

Do you want this job?
Than you need to research every power of persuasion out there.
1. Do not admit to a lie.
2. Take a moral high ground.

> "From past experience, companies discriminant against those without a
>   degree. Either through automated filtering of resumes, or direct
>   hiring biases. It is unfortunate, but this was required in order to cut through
>   discrimination to showcase my skills that I can bring to your company,
>   sans degree...."

Someone with better persuasion and manipulation can likely come up with a phrasing far more powerful that what is presented above. Many will dislike this comment. But apologizing, or whatever is stated above, will not get you the job. good luck!

Comment: Um... what? How can somebody who was caught in a lie "take the moral high ground"? Did you mean "attempt to steal the moral high ground"?

Comment: That means in addition to lying implicitly accuse the company recruiters of some sort of unfair discrimination. Yes, I'd definitely would want someone in my company that tries to twist the truth by making up accusations and that uses illegal routes to achieve what she/he thinks is right, I wouldn't see any lawsuits coming up in the future from or due to that employee. Btw. the example actually does admit to a lie, just doesn't call it by name or apologize for it.

Comment: Speaking as an employer, if one of my candidates (or new hires) said something like this, I would cancel their application (or show them the door) before I even reached the end of the paragraph. "I lied to you because lying is the only way I know to succeed" is not a good justification.

Comment: I understand the visceral response that makes people want to downvote this as it comes across as 'when confronted with the lie, go on the offensive' but if the candidate/employee _actually_ has such experience, this would be an _honest_ explanation for why they did it, and probably their best chance. The company/recruiter would not necessarily need to be corrupt or incompetent to accept it as an explanation, frustration/desperation can lead people to do things they wouldn't otherwise do. They would however be foolish to accept it without further investigation to verify it is an anomaly.

Comment: This is terrible advice. There's a reason why job boards and applications usually have the option of attaching a cover letter or portfolio. This is is to help showcase and let the recruiters know what you've done/can do even if you have no formal/accredited degree or professional experience.

Comment: @paulj - A good indication that you might need to rethink your approach: you're trying to explain that the right answer is psychologically manipulative persuasiveness... yet you're not able to persuade people that your method is a good idea.

Comment: "Take a moral high ground." - The only way to do that would be to admit to the lie.  Discrimination is a poor word choice.  This answer is just bad advice....

Comment: @Mr.Mindor I wouldn't have a problem with the general explanation that one did do this to not be overlooked if it was a) phrased defensive rather than aggressive b) the sub-tone of the message was not to double-down in trying to get the job by all manipulative means but c) that was the actual reasoning and the OP is aware that it was a lie and an amoral likely illegal choice to counter a perceived disadvantage.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I always wish I could make my comments better fit my intent, but I'm a rather verbose person, and by the time I cut them down enough to fit the box I lose so much. I agree with your last comment completely, but ended up trimming my version of parts a and b for "brevity". (In the end I only had like 10 characters left anyway)